# One table many classes

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Say I have a database structure like this:

```
create table Product(id int not null identity,Name varchar(30))
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('ProductA')
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('ProductB')
```

and a class structure like this:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Product

    Protected ProductName As String

    Public Overridable Sub Display()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ProductA
    Inherits Product

    Public Sub New(ByVal product As String)
        ProductName = product
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Display()
        'Specific logic to display product A
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ProductB
    Inherits Product

    Public Sub New(ByVal product As String)
        ProductName = product
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Display()
        'Specific logic to display product B
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim p1 As Product
        Dim p2 As Product

        p1 = New ProductA("ProductA")
        p2 = New ProductB("ProductB")
        p1.Display()
        p2.Display()
    End Sub
End Class
```

There is a Property (Product) that identifies, which product the class relates to.  This does not look correct to me.  Is there a better way of modelling it? This is similar to the NHibernate concept of a Discriminator (I am not using NHibernate in this case).

Comment: I see no real question..modelling it to do what, exactly?  Seems like a unnecessary inheritance, unless there's more than you are showing here (which I assume there is).

Comment: It depends. This question needs more context.

Comment: @fab, I have added more code in an attempt to make the question clearer.

Comment: Still nothing that justifies different classes for ProductA and ProductB

Comment: @fab, I have edited the code again.  I am trying to explain the problem using a simple example.  The actual problem domain is much more complex.

Comment: Now it looks like the product classes have too many responsibilities (i.e. more than one) - it's always better to separate business logic and presentation. I know, you said, the actual domain is more complex, but if this means your example does not tell me much about your actual design decisions, you cannot get a specific answer. I'll link you a generic one, hth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/664108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you latest change, you should move your constructor to the base class. Aside from that, the design is fine.

```
Public Class Product

    Protected ProductName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal product As String)
        ProductName = product
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub Display()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ProductA
    Inherits Product

    Public Overrides Sub Display()
        'Specific logic to display product A
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also, in your declarations you can use the inherited class:

```
Dim p1 As ProductA
Dim p2 As ProductB
```

Comment: I have added more code in an attempt to make the question clearer.

Comment: The inherited classes override functions and sub routines from the base class.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of ProductA to ProductZ.  Then you would have to change the client code to reflect it i.e. change p1 = New ProductA("ProductA") in Form_Load to: p1 = New ProductA("ProductZ").  I was wandering if there was a way of avoiding this.  Perhaps I am overthinking the problem?

Comment: @w0051977 If a single `Product` class can only have one product name (i.e. class `ProductA` can only have `ProductName = "ProductA"`) then it should be hardcoded, like you had it originally. What's the point of loading the name from the DB at that point?

Comment: In case the name ever changes.  I don't think it ever will, but I believe that other develoeprs cater for scenarios like this.